# Tikz: Plot of an implicit function using contour gnuplot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, gnuplot

I tried to plot an implicit function. I keep getting the same error message: "undefined variable: set".

Thanks in advance.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.fillbetween} 
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    title={Implicit Function Plot},
    xlabel={$x$},
    ylabel={$y$},
    xmin=0, xmax=50,
    ymin=0, ymax=50,
    view={0}{90}, % 
]

\addplot3[
    thick,
    contour gnuplot={levels={0}, labels=false}, % Adjust 'levels' as needed
    samples=50, % Increase for higher resolution
    samples y=50, % Explicitly defining samples y for clarity
    domain=0:50,
    domain y=0:50,
] 
    gnuplot {
        set contour base;
        set cntrparam levels discrete 0;
        unset surface;
        set view map;
        splot -1/2*(x+y)**(-1/2)*x + 100 - (x+y)**(1/2) - 2*x;
    };

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]

In the figure we can see the level curve for the function `f(x, y) = x/(2\sqrt{x +y}) +\sqrt{x +y} +2x` corresponding to the value 20.  Note that the questioner's goal was to represent the level curve for 100.

The solution is based on some computations that yield `y` as a function of `x` (mainly solving quadratic equations).  Of course there is a condition of positivity that gives the domain for `x`.  The drawing is based on TikZ and not on pgfplots.  I don't know how to make the command `contour` works.

The functions drawn are named `tmpM` and `tmpP` and introduced as such; they are drawn on the union of two intervals whose bounds are computed by the functions `xLIni` (i.e. initial x of the left interval), ...

In the code below, there is a variable `\a` which is set to 10; it corresponds to the value `2*\a` for the level curve.

**Remark.** The numbers involved become too big very quickly.  For this reason, the units must be modified globally (see `[x=6.7pt, y=.1pt]`).

**The code**

```
\documentclass[11pt, margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math}

\begin{document}

\tikzmath{%
  function xLIni(\c) {%
    return {\c -2*\c};
  };
  function xLEnd(\c) {%
    return {(2*\c +1/2 -pow(2*\c +1/4, .5))/2};
  };
  function xRIni(\c) {%
    return {(2*\c +1/2 +pow(2*\c +1/4, .5))/2};
  };
  function xREnd(\c) {%
    return {\c +2*\c};
  };
  function tmpM(\t, \c) {%
    \tmp = (\t -\c)*(\t -\c) -\t/2;
    return {2*\tmp -\t/2 -2*(\t -\c)*pow(\tmp, .5)};
  };
  function tmpP(\t, \c) {%
    \tmp = (\t -\c)*(\t -\c) -\t/2;
    return {2*\tmp -\t/2 +2*(\t -\c)*pow(\tmp, .5)};
  };
}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=6.7pt, y=.1pt,
  evaluate={\a = 10; \b = int(\a*\a); \cst = int(2*\a);}]
  \draw[->] ({xLIni(\a) -1}, 0) -- ({xREnd(\a) +1}, 0) node[above] {$x$};
  \draw[->] (0, -.2) -- (0, {1.7*xREnd(\a)*xREnd(\a)}) node[left] {$y$};

  \draw (\a, 0) -- +(0, 20) -- +(0, -20) node[below] {$\a$};
  \draw (0, \b) -- +(.3, 0) -- +(-.3, 0) node[left] {$\b$};
  
  \begin{scope}[every path/.style={%
      blue, very thick, variable=\t, samples=100
    }]
    \draw[domain={xLIni(\a)}:{xLEnd(\a)}] plot (\t, {tmpM(\t, \a)});
    \draw[domain={xLIni(\a)}:{xLEnd(\a)}] plot (\t, {tmpP(\t, \a)});
    \draw[domain={xRIni(\a)+.05}:{xREnd(\a)}] plot (\t, {tmpP(\t, \a)});
    \draw[domain={xRIni(\a)+.05}:{xREnd(\a)}] plot (\t, {tmpM(\t, \a)});      
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the `gnuplot` `set` syntax, you have to invoke it with the `raw gnuplot` option.

Unless you really need raw `gnuplot` to do things that are not supported by `pgfplots`, I would recommend using `gnuplot` from within `pgfplots` as shown below. Note that the function to be plotted must be *in `pgfplots` math syntax, i.e., you need to use `^` instead of `**`.*

EDIT: Gnuplot needs `write18` (external commands) enabled. Compile using `pdflatex --shell-escape file.tex`.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.fillbetween} 
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
      title={Implicit Function Plot},
      xlabel={$x$},
      ylabel={$y$},
      xmin=0, xmax=50,
      ymin=0, ymax=50,
      view={0}{90}, % 
      ]
      \addplot3[
        thick,
        contour gnuplot={levels={0,10,20,30}, labels=false},
        samples=100, 
        samples y=100,
        domain=0:50,
        domain y=0:50,
        ]{-1/2*(x+y)^(-1/2)*x + 100 - (x+y)^(1/2) - 2*x};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

You can also use `contour lua` to entirely bypass `gnuplot` in favor of compilation using `lualatex`. For more details on `pgfplots` contour plots, see [the `pgfplots` manual](https://tikz.dev/pgfplots/reference-3dplots#sec-17.8).

Comment: If I try to use the code you provided (with `pdflatex`, I get the following error: `Package pgfplots Error: sorry, plot file{contour_contourtmp0.table} could not be opened.`

Comment: When using `gnuplot`, you have to call `pdflatex` with external commands enabled. On Windows, try `pdflatex.exe --shell-escape "document.tex"`. If you do not want to do that, just replace `contour gnuplot` with `contour lua` and use `lualatex.exe document.tex` to compile.